# Reading and writing child relationships of not-yet persisted SObjects?

Tags: apex, relationships, master-detail

I have a `Parent__c` and `Child__c` custom object connected by a `lkp_Parent__c` field. I now create an in-memory version (no insert) of a parent-child tree

```
Parent__c p = new Parent__c();
Child__c c = new Child(lkp_Parent__r = p);
p.Childs__r.add(c);
...
```

and try to read it

```
for(Child__c c : p.Childs__r) {
   ...
}
```

**But `Childs__r` is empty? What did I do wrong? Is there no way to use SObjects purely in-memory?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked Adrian's answer so much, I wanted to share how I used it to generate sObject test data without requiring DML. This let me test some really ugly logic that covered 20+ variations on Account/Contact/User record relationships.

The key was that I didn't need Ids, and I could run and test the logic separately from any queries and insert/update calls. In my case, this was much lighter than mocking DML calls.

Proxy classes:

```
class ParentProxy {
    private Map<String,ChildListProxy> children;
    private Type t;
    
    ParentProxy(Type apexType) {
        t = apexType;
        children = new Map<String,ChildListProxy>();
    }
    
    public void addChildList(String label, List<SObject> records) {
        children.put(label, new ChildListProxy(records));
    }
    
    public SObject generateParent() {
        return (SObject)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(children), t);
    }
    
    public SObject generateParent(Map<String,Object> parentFields) {
        SObject so = generateParent();
        for(String field : parentFields) {
            so.put(field, parentFields.get(field));
        }
        return so;
    }
}

class ChildListProxy {
    final List<SObject> records;
    Integer totalSize { get { return records.size(); } }
    Boolean done = true;

    ChildListProxy(List<SObject> children) {
        records = children;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// generates some Contact records with test data
List<Contact> childContacts = generateContactData();

// generates Account fields with test data
// also can use SObject.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()
Map<String,Object> accountFields = new Map<String,Object> {
    'Name' => 'SomeCorp',
    'Magic_Number__c' => 42
}; 

ParentProxy accountProxy = new ParentProxy(Account.class);
accountProxy.addChildList('Contacts', childContacts);
        
Account testAccount = (Account)accountProxy.generateParent(accountFields);
```

Comment: You might like to consider using [SObjectFabricator](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator) for in-memory-only mock data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a look! 

If I'm gong for something heavier, I really like the light weight DML mocking setup from James Simone: https://github.com/jamessimone/apex-dml-mocking and https://github.com/jamessimone/apex-mocks-stress-test

Answer (score 7):

You can do it via serialization if you want to go that far:

```
class Proxy
{
    final List<Child__c> records;
    Proxy(List<Child__c> children) { records = children; }
    Integer totalSize { get { return records.size(); } }
    Boolean done = true;
}

List<Child__c> children = new List<Child__c> { new Child__c(Name='Demo') };
String childPayload = JSON.serialize(new Proxy(children));
String payload = '{"Children__r": ' + childPayload + '}';

MyObject__c record = (MyObject__c)JSON.deserialize(payload, MyObject__c.class);
system.assertEquals(children.size(), record.Children__r.size());
```

---

A couple notes I found interesting about the `done` and `totalSize` properties:

- If you do not specify `done = true`, you will get an error:

  > System.QueryException: Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop
- If you do not specify `totalSize`, none of the records will get added to the collection and you will again wind up with an empty child list!