# How to get sObject with 3+ levels of child relationships

Tags: apex

I want to build data structure with 3 levels of related objects. 
In query it is possible to get only 2 levels:

```
SELECT Name, (select Name from Children__r) FROM Parent__c
```

So I am trying to do this in code. I want to manually query child records and based on Id assign them to parent. But I get error when trying to do this:

```
parent.Children__r = new List<Child__c>();
```

Saying 'Field is not writable'.

And just doing this `parent.Children__r.add(child);` results in empty list.
Is there any way to achieve this **without using wrappers**?

Comment: As far as setting the child relationship in memory: [Reading and writing child relationships of not-yet persisted SObjects?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/172925/2995)

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can obtain 5 levels going from child to parent so 3 levels would be e.g.:

```
select Name, Parent1__r.Name, Parent1__r.Parent2__r.Name from Children__c
```

But the semantics are different e.g. if there are no children objects you will get no parent objects. Sometimes useful.

Other than that it's (ugly) wrappers...

Comment: I am building tree component in lightning (need strictly parent with children etc). Unfortunetly this approach would require too much code. And I guess there is no way to bypass wrappers for lightning. But anyway, thanks